# How to create deep-link url for my android app on play store and paste it on facebook product page of the game? [screenshot]

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

What really to post in the area of App Link where it asks to "Add a Android deep link URL to your app."?

Trivial, I guess, for everyone out here, but I am struggling.

[image]

Comment: it is the link when you click on it, it will open a chooser or your app based on schema.. here `example://` is the schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Android Manifest, you can declare that certain activities are able to view certain uri's - such as

```
yourapp://view/specific/content/at/this/uri
```

The intent filter for this in your activity could be

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE/>
        <data android:scheme="yourapp"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

See https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: now I get it. many thanks. let me implement it and hopefully I will get back with some problems to bug you again. If not then you know you have my thanks. ;) Jokes apart, thank you.